# SubDoc operation in couchbase

Tags: couchbase

I am using this code to fetch subDocumnent from a specific document

```
 DocumentFragment<Lookup> result= bucket.async().lookupIn(docId).get(subDocId).execute().
          toBlocking().singleOrDefault(null);
```

I am not sure why but

```
result.rawContent(subDocId)
```

returns **null**, whereas

```
result.content(subDocId)
```

returns the proper value.

Can anyone point to me what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Adding **includeRaw(true)** did the trick

```
DocumentFragment<Lookup> result =  couchbaseBucket.async().lookupIn(docId).get(subDocId).includeRaw(true).execute().
              toBlocking().singleOrDefault(null);
```